# Express and Node (CouchDB) fails to return list filled with data

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, nunjucks

I am attempting to return "checkins_each" but it is returning a blank list [] every attempt at displaying it. I think the checkins.list() is running in a new thread or something same with checkins.get() running in a new thread - is there a proper way to return checkins_each - it should have a few records in it?

console.log(jsondoc) shows that jsondoc is indeed a large json data structure

```
// return data
var checkins = nano.use(settings.COUCHDB_PREFIX+'checkins');
var checkins_each = [];
checkins.list(function(err, body) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('hi proximity loop')
        body.rows.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id);
            checkins.get(doc.id, function(err,jsondoc) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondoc));
                if (jsondoc.profile_id != profile_id) {
                    console.log('appending checkin');
                    checkins_each.push(jsondoc);
                }

            });
        });
        res.send({status: 'proximity', checkins: checkins_each});
    } else {
        console.log("error", err);
        res.send({status: 'fail', error: err});

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must read about async calls and use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [async-lib](https://github.com/caolan/async) or like below

```
var checkins = nano.use(settings.COUCHDB_PREFIX+'checkins');
checkins.list(function(err, body) {
    if (err) 
        return res.send({status: 'fail', error: err});

    var checkins_each = [];
    function getRow(i) {
        if (i == body.rows)
            return res.send({status: 'proximity', checkins: checkins_each});

        var doc = body.rows[i];
        checkins.get(doc.id, function(err, jsondoc) {
            if (err)
                return res.send({status: 'fail', error: err});

            if (jsondoc.profile_id != profile_id)
                checkins_each.push(jsondoc);

            getRow(i + 1);
        });
    };

    getRow(0);
}
```

If `checkins.get` returns Promise then the code can be like below

```
var checkins = nano.use(settings.COUCHDB_PREFIX+'checkins');
checkins.list(function(err, body) {
    if (err) 
        return res.send({status: 'fail', error: err});

    var promises = body.rows.map((row) => checkins.get(row.id));
    Promise.All(promises)
        .then(function (results) {
            var checkins_each = [];
            results
                .filter((res) => res.profile_id != profile_id)
                .forEach((res) => checkins_each.push(res))

            res.send({status: 'proximity', checkins: checkins_each});
        })
        .catch(err) {
            return res.send({status: 'fail', error: err});
        }
})
```

Comment: I attempted your code as follows but and installed the node package Promise as required, but still the checkins_each array returns [] empty.

Comment: Promises is a part of JavaScript as `for` and `function` (I don't know what kind of package you installed). I'm not sure that `checkins.get` returns `promise`-object. You can simple check it by `console.log`.

Comment: You don't need that package. The code `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { throw new Error("o_O") }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));` works without any dependencies in Node. Check that some result returns via `console.log(results)`. If it's empty then check `row.id` and appropriate `checkins.get(row.id)` contains any data.

Comment: Aikon, someone told me to use the callbacks.

Comment: `Callback` and `promise` are methods to do async calls. The first code uses pure js-callbacks but this code is weird. You can use `async`-lib to write the more usual code. Another way is [`async/await`](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt based on Aikon's code, still returning empty an empty checkins_each as [] for some reason:

```
var checkins = nano.use(settings.COUCHDB_PREFIX+'checkins');
checkins.list(function(err, body) {
    if (err) 
        return res.send({status: 'fail', error: err});

    var promises = body.rows.map((row) => checkins.get(row.id));
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function (results) {
            var checkins_each = [];
            results
                .filter((res) => res.profile_id != profile_id)
                .forEach((res) => checkins_each.push(res))

            res.send({status: 'proximity', checkins: checkins_each});
        })

});
```